# Make this work for iPad as well?

Tags: iphone, image, ipad, load

How to make this work for iPad as well? it works fine on iphone but Apple requires that all apps should work on ipad. any help with this?

```
  - (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender
    {
        self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
        [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];


        [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

    - (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
    {
        self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [self.imageView setImage:self.image];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    - (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

---

Now I've got this far! It doesn't crash anymore now when I pick an image from the photo library using the ipad. The problem is that the image doesn't get picked?

Any suggestions?

```
- (IBAction)chooseImage:(id)sender
{

self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
[self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){

    _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:_imagePicker];
    _popover.delegate = self;
    [_popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 460)];
    [_popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:(UIButton*)sender] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}

[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
if
    (self.popover && self.popover.popoverVisible) {
    [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
else
    self.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self.imageView setImage:self.image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: Is your app iPhone-only or is it universal? If it is iPhone-only then your code is fine. If it's universal then you must show the photo library image picker in a `UIPopoverController` as explained in the docs for `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: my app is iphone only and this works perfectly on iphone. but to my surprise, when admitting this app to appstore, they apparently require that ALL apps should have support for iPad. So I wonder if i can comply with that without having to change to universal?

Comment: An iPhone-only app will run on the iPad just fine as long as you aren't doing something specific to mess it up. The requirement to use the photo library image picker in a popover only applies to iPad-only apps or universal apps running on the iPad. iPhone-only apps that happen to be on the iPad do not have this requirement. You are fine with the posted code.

Comment: Yeah, what he said (again). Did they actually ding you or are you just making up these worries?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I made an app that takes an image, let the user alter it in some ways, and then send it to another app.
The app got rejected because the reviewer didn't have that other app installed so he thought that my app was broken.

It also happened that the reviewer is testing it on an iPad and when I tried that at home I discovered that the imagepicker doesn't work on an ipad. So I'm trying to adjust even though my app is an iphone only app. I'm getting frustrated so I can't think clear right now.

Comment: App Store Review Guidlines

2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Comment: Ensure the project settings make it iPhone-only. Click on the project name in the upper left of the project/file window and under Summary ensure iPad is not selected/checked/whatever. The Info section might have something also

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've selected iPhone only. Double checked every setting and it's totally iPad free. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the section from my book on UIImagePickerController:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch30.html#_uiimagepickercontroller

Okay, sorry, no universal code. But it works just the same way architecturally as for MPMediaPickerController, for which I do give code showing how to do it on both iPhone and iPad:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch29.html#EXmodalOrPop

It's tricky because popover management is very different from presented view controller management. That code shows you some of what you have to worry about...

Here is *actual* code from a universal app I just wrote:

```
- (IBAction)doPickAPicture:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType type = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    BOOL ok = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:type];
    if (!ok) {
        return;
    }
    UIImagePickerController* picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
    picker.sourceType = type;
    picker.mediaTypes = @[(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    else {
        UIPopoverController* pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
        [pop presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds] inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        self.currentPop = pop;
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    if (self.currentPop && self.currentPop.popoverVisible) {
        [self.currentPop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        self.currentPop = nil;
        // do more stuff
    }];
}
```